# SpringJDBC ClassPathXmlApplicationContext unable to load getbean from xml in resources

Tags: java, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am noob in java. i want to insert data into employe table.

> ***Err: No bean named 'employeeDAO.class' is defined.***
>
> **my code structure:**

[image]

This is my code.

> file: com.vm.springjdbc.app.App.java

```
public class App {
    private ApplicationContext context;
    private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Datasource.xml");
        employeeDAO = (EmployeeDAO) context.getBean("employeeDAO.class");
    }
}
```

> file: com.vm.springjdbc.model.Employee.java

```
public class Employee { 
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String mobile;
    setter & getter
}
```

> file: com.vm.springjdbc.DAO.EmployeDAO.java

```
public class EmployeeDAO extends JdbcDaoSupport {   
    public void insert(Employee emp){       
    }
}
```

> Xml file in resources:src/resources/Spring-Datasource.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/synapse4" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="admin" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="employeeDAO" class="com.vm.springjdbc.DAO.EmployeeDAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

> Please help me to sort it out

Comment: Please provide full error log

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'employeeDAO.class' is defined. at line : employeeDAO = (EmployeeDAO) context.getBean("employeeDAO.class");

Comment: is employeeDAO has setter class for DAO or autowiring.

Comment: no, employeeDAO is empty. I followd the below link https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-jdbcdaosupport-examples/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the EmployeeDAO as interface and make an impl class for this EmployeeDAOImpl as follows:

> EmployeeDAO.java

```
public interface EmployeeDAO 
{
    public void insert(Employee employee);
}
```

> EmployeeDAOImpl.java

```
public class EmployeeDAOImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements EmployeeDAO
{
    public void insert(Employee employee){
        //insertion implementation
    }

}
```

and make the following changes in Spring-Datasource.xml

```
<bean id="employeeDAO" class="com.vm.springjdbc.DAO.EmployeeDAOImpl">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Also, please do not use .class in

```
employeeDAO = (EmployeeDAO) context.getBean("employeeDAO.class");
```

change it to

```
employeeDAO = (EmployeeDAO) context.getBean("employeeDAO");
```

Comment: I want to use JdbcDaoSupport. So, where I do want to extend the JdbcDaoSupport? Tq @Kayv

Comment: No bean named 'employeeDAOImpl.class' is defined. Still didn't worked. can you check my folder structure and code as well agin Tq. @kayv

Comment: @chandoo you need to create a new file in com.vm.springjdbc.DAO named EmployeeDAOImpl.java and put the above bean in Spring-Datasource.xml

Comment: Yes @KayV I did the same added the bean in Xml located in resources folder and created EmployeeDAOImpl class file. 
public class EmployeeDAOImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements EmployeeDAO {....}
Changed the EmployeeDAO to interface.

Comment: Now what is the error? Have to build the project? Is everything compiling fine?

Comment: it is maven project and build the project. runtime error is No bean named 'employeeDAOImpl.class' is defined. @KayV

Comment: changed to getBean("employeeDAO"); The error is->  the No bean named 'employeeDAOImpl' is defined. @KayV

Comment: your answer worked for me, You answered correct but, in hurry you made small typos. Do one change in EmployeeDAOImpl.java file. EmployeeDAOImpl is not interface and the classname is also wrong. so,If you made these changes I will check it as answer. As some people may get confuse on this regard. tq.

Comment: @chandoo thanks for pointing the typos. Updated the answer as suggested. Pls proceed.